# django-autoslug not populating database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using the django-autoslug package with a project and, though the documentation is simple enough, I cannot get it to populate the database field with the slug.

models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```

I have also tried overriding the save() method with both an `AutoSlugField` and a regular `SlugField`, but this did not work either.

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.slug = slugify(self.title)
     super(Thread, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For example, when I create a thread with the title "This should create a slug", I would expect the "slug" field in the database to be populated with "this-should-create-a-slug".  Instead, it is only being populate with an empty string: ''

Does anyone know what might cause this? I have not been able to find documentation of any similar issues with either the django-autoslug package or just overriding the save() method with a regular `SlugField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself after restarting my computer. No idea why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using "autoslug" library is not necesary create slug into 
(save) function model. You can remove the next line from your code :)

self.slug = slugify(self.title)